# Firebase retrieving doc ref, but not by equivalent query. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

If I create a document reference, and fetch it with `getDoc`, I get the document back just fine, but if I do a **query** for `id == 'adsadasfsge'` or `id in ['adsadasfsge']` on the same database, I get nothing back. Here's the code I'm trying:

```
    // Directly fetching one doc by id, using a docRef
    const dr = doc(firestore, 'TestPrograms', id);
    getDoc(dr).then((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.exists());
    });

    // Fetching with an unambiguous == query
    const q = query(collection(firestore, 'TestPrograms'), where('id', '==', id));
    getDocs(q).then((docs) => {
      console.log(docs.size);
    });
    // Fetching with an 'in' query
    const q2 = query(collection(firestore, 'TestPrograms'), where('id', 'in', [id]));
    getDocs(q2).then((docs) => {
      console.log(docs.size);
    });
```

Running this logs:

```
true
0
0
```

I'm baffled. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: We can't see the contents of the document to know that the query would actually find it.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of a document that you'd expect this code to return?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen's answer hit the nail on the head. I was unaware of the specific sentinel value for `documentId`. The fact that I didn't post the contents of the document was, I suspect, actually the critical clue. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query checks for **a field** named `id` inside the document with a specific value. If you want to check for documents whose **document ID** has a specific value, you need to specify the special [`documentId()` marker](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#documentid) as the field for the query.

Comment: Wow. I'm new to the platform, so maybe this is one of those lessons you just have to learn the hard way, but this is very much NOT obvious. For instance, `documentId()` isn't mentioned once on the page about "Read Data" in the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data). Seems like an oversight to me, but maybe I'm just worked up at the moment. :)

Comment: Good point. I'm often looking for code samples with `documentId()` there too, and then end up linking to the reference docs. Would you mind leaving feedback on the page?\

Comment: Sure! And thank you for such a quick and spot-on response! Feedback sent.